# How to download apk file from parse server and install it automatically

Tags: android

I have never use Parse.I have a a table on parse having two columns one for versioncode and second column for APK.

I have app of version code 2 in my android device.Now I want to implement the logic if my app version code and version code on parse database is different then I want to download the apk file using ParseFile on background and once download is complete then install automatically.

Please help me .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this not malicious? Users should always be able to decide if you install an app. The google play store does not allow apps that update themselves in any other way then the play store.

Comment: No once the download is complete then popup for install is shown to user and when user clicks on install button then only it install in device

Answer (score 1):

This opens the install window of the package manager:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"),
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

I don't know what happens when you replace the URI with an URL, but i guess it won't work